# How can i extend the menu bar of visual studio code by adding my own menu?

Tags: menu, vscode-extensions

I would like to develop a debugger extension in visual studio code so that new menu in the menu bar is created when the debugger is launched for my c code.

Is it possible to create such a plugin extension in visual studio code?

Is it possible to extend menu bar at all in visual studio code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can contribute commands to several menus in vscode. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) is a list to which parts you can contribute your command items.

For example, if you want to add an item to the *debug toolbar*, you can do so by adding it to the related menu:

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "menus": {
      "debug/toolBar": [
        {
          "command": "yourExtension.yourCommand",
          "when": "inDebugMode",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note, that you have to register your command in your *extension.ts*/*extension.js* and and also in your *package.json* first, e.g.:

extension.ts:

```js
vscode.commands.registerCommand('yourExtension.yourCommand', () => {
    console.log("Hello World");
});
```

and in your *package.json*

```json
"commands": [
    {
      "command": "yourExtension.yourCommand",
      "title": "Hello World"
    }
  ]
```

---

If you want to specify conditions, when the command should be shown, you can do so by adding *when* conditions. In the given example, the item is only shown, while *debugMode* is active.
Here is a list of possible arguments in your *when* clause:
[link](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts)

Comment: Thanks. I tried with above suggestions. I get error saying "debug/toolbar is not a valid menu identifier. Here is my package.json looks something like this
 "contributes": {
 "menus": {
  "debug/toolbar": [
    {
   "command": "HelloWord.helloWorld",
   "when": "inDebugMode",
   "group": "navigation"
    }
  ]
 },
 
 "commands": [
  {
   "command": "HelloWord.helloWorld",
   "title": "Hello World from me"
  }
 ]


   },

Am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: It seems like, it is "debug/toolBar" instead of "debug/toolbar" (a capital B in Bar). I fixed it, so it should work, when you replace it, as well.